# Excel formula where the outcome remains unchanged when values change in future

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
     A            B            C
1   Area        constant    Land value
2  0.2500       200,000      50,000.00
3  0.3650       200,000      73,000.00
4  1.2540       200,000     250,800.00
5  0.2580       200,000      51,600.00
```

In the above excel sheet columns C2 to C5 hold the formula `=(A2*B2)`, `=(A3*B3)`,  `=(A4*B4)`, `=(A5*B5)`. Help me with a formula where the answers in cells C2, C3, C4 and C5 remain unchanged when values in column A or B change.

Comment: Why do you need a formula if you don't want it to calculate? Do you want to be fixed after first calculation? Are all the input values entered at the same time, or it's filled step by step? Please give a bit more background to your question. Please don't answer in a comment, but edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Select cells **C2** through **C5**, copy them, and then PasteSpecialValues back on top of them.

This will convert the formula results into hard values that will not change.